# Question about the Fourier Transform

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

Suppose $f$ is continuous and of moderate decrease. i.e.

$$|f(x)| \le \frac C{1+x^2},\forall x \in \mathbb R, C>0$$

For fixed $t \in \mathbb R$:
$$A(z)=\int_{- \infty}^{t} f(x)e^{-2\pi iz(x-t)}dx$$

and
$$B(z)=- \int_{t}^{\infty} f(x)e^{-2\pi iz(x-t)}dx$$

The aim is to show that $A(\xi) = B(\xi)$, $\forall \xi \in \mathbb R$

Using this result, the second aim is to prove that the function:

$$F=\begin{cases}
A,  & \text{in the closed upper half plane} \\
B, & \text{in the lower half plane}  \\
\end{cases}$$

is entire and bounded and therefore constant.

Honestly, I've been working at the this problem for a while now and I think I can prove $|A(\xi)| = |B(\xi)|$ but that's not the same so I'm not sure...

Comment: Nudge: I'm pretty sure that $F$ has to equal $0$ if it meets all the criteria of the proof

Comment: What do you mean by $\vert A(\xi) \vert$ if $t$ is not fixed?

Comment: It is. I've edited the problem

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Take
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
1+\frac{x}{2} & \text{ for }\, -2 \le x< 0\\
1-x & \text{ for }\, 0\le x\le 1\\
0     & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}.
$$
It is clear that for $C>0$ large enough
$$
|f(x)|\le \frac{C}{1+x^2} \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
For $t=0$ we have
\begin{eqnarray}
A(z)&=&\int_{-2}^0f(x)e^{-2\pi izx}\,dx=\int_{-2}^0(1+\frac{x}{2})e^{-2\pi izx}\,dx=\frac{2+x}{-4\pi iz}e^{-2\pi izx}\Big|_{-2}^0+\frac{1}{4\pi iz}\int_{-2}^0e^{-2\pi izx}\,dx\\
&=&\frac{i}{2\pi z}+\frac{1-e^{2\pi iz}}{8\pi^2z^2},\\
B(z)&=&-\int_0^1f(x)e^{-2\pi izx}\,dx=-\int_0^1(1-x)e^{-2\pi izx}\,dx=-\frac{1-x}{-2\pi iz}e^{-2\pi izx}\Big|_0^1+\frac{1}{2\pi iz}\int_0^1e^{-2\pi izx}\,dx\\
&=&\frac{i}{2\pi z}-\frac{1-e^{-2\pi iz}}{4\pi^2z^2}.
\end{eqnarray}
You can also show that if $t \in (-1,1)$ then you always have $A\not\equiv B$.

Comment: I can't find a flaw in this counter-example (except that $B(z) =$ the negative of the integral but $A$ and $B$ still aren't equal. The problem, however, explicitly states that the proof is to show $A(\xi) = B(\xi)$ so now I'm confused...